# Node.js decrypting encrypted string from MySQL causes EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length

Tags: mysql, node.js, encryption

I have 2 functions in an encryption service class. 1 to encrypt data, and 1 to decrypt data.

```
export default class EncryptionService {

    private static algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'; 

    private static key = createHash('sha256').update(String('keyString')).digest('base64').substr(0, 32);
    private static iv = Buffer.from('ivString');

    public static encryptData(data: string): string {
        const cipher = createCipheriv(this.algorithm, this.key, this.iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(data);
        encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
        const encryptedStr = encrypted.toString('base64');
        console.log('encryptedStr: ' + encryptedStr);
        return encryptedStr;
    }

    public static decryptData(data: string): string {
        const decipher = createDecipheriv(this.algorithm, this.key, this.iv);
        const decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'base64');
        const decryptedData = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]).toString();
        console.log('decryptedData: ' + decryptedData);
        return decryptedData;
    }
}
```

In my controller, when I call the encryptData function then immediately call the decryptData function, passing in the encrypted data returned from the encryptData function, I get the correct unencrypted string back.

```
import EncryptionService from '../services/encryption-service';

export default class MyController {
  public async postData(request: Request, response: Response) {

    const encryptedAudioFileName = EncryptionService.encryptData(request.body.audio_file_name);
    EncryptionService.decryptData(encryptedAudioFileName);
  }
}
```

However - when I store the encrypted Data returned from encryptData into mySQL via a post function in the controller and then attempt to decrypt the data retrieved from mySQL via a get function in the controller, an error occurs in the decryptData function stating "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length".

```
  public async postData(request: Request, response: Response) {
    Logger.info(request, response, 'Request Received');

    try {
      if (request.body) {
        const dataEntity = new dataEntity();
        dataEntity.audio_file_name = EncryptionService.encryptData(request.body.audio_file_name);

        const result = await getManager().save<dataEntity>(dataEntity);
        if (result) {
          const responseObject = {
            timestamp: new Date().toUTCString(),
            method: request.method,
            status: 'Success',
            statusCode: 201,
            message: 'successfully created.',
            path: request.originalUrl,
            reference: result.id,
          };
          Logger.success(request, response, responseObject);
          response.status(201).json(responseObject);
        } else {
          response.status(400).json(
            ResponseService.badRequestErrorResponseObject(request, response));
        }
      } else {
        response.status(400).json(
          ResponseService.badRequestErrorResponseObject(request, response, 'Body is invalid'));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).json(
        ResponseService.internalErrorResponseObject(request, response, error));
    }
  }

  public async getData(request: Request, response: Response) {
    Logger.info(request, response, 'Request Received');

    try {
      const allData: dataEntity[] =
        await getConnectionManager().get().getRepository(dataEntity).find();
      if (allData) {
        const entityResponseArray = [] as object[];
        allData.forEach( (entity) => {
          const dataResponse = {} as {id: number, audioFileName: string};
          dataResponse.id = entity.id!;
          dataResponse.audioFileName = EncryptionService.decryptData(entity.audio_file_name!);

          entityResponseArray.push(dataResponse);
        });

        Logger.success(request, response, 'Get list of data');
        response.json(entityResponseArray);
      } else {
        response.status(404).json(
          ResponseService.notFoundErrorResponseObject(request, response));
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).json(
        ResponseService.internalErrorResponseObject(request, response, error));
    }
  }
```

It happens at this line in decryptData:

```
const decryptedData = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]).toString();
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: can you show your table structure by running the SQL `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`. What length is stored? What length is retrieved?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audio_file_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `audio_dialogue` mediumtext,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idtable_name_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: I think you solved my issue @danblack. I changed the size of the column to varchar(100) and it works now. I'm such an idiot... thanks for the insight.

Comment: The default way languages hide mysql errors makes it hard to see. If storing base64 encoded specify a latin1 8 character set for the `[var]char` column. If storing raw data use `varbinary` rather than `varchar`. (or just `binary` if its a fixed length)

Comment: I ultimately used a blob for all of my columns that require encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my column length and or type. The encrypt and decrypt code works fine. The data returning from mysql was being cut off so it couldn't decrypt properly. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the insight.